# NSButton RadioGroup (NSMatrix Alternative)

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I've tried a few times to set up several similar buttons, all connected to the same IBActions, and still can't seem to replicate the RadioButton Behaviour.

At the moment, I have 5 Buttons, all children of one NSView..

```
NSView
    - ButtonOne - NSButton (Square Button)
    - ButtonTwo - NSButton (Square Button)
    - ButtonThree - NSButton (Square Button)
    - ButtonFour - NSButton (Square Button)
    - ButtonFive - NSButton (Square Button)
```

They're all connected to a common IBAction, which reads as:

```
@IBAction func activityButtonPressed(sender: NSButton) {

    println("\(sender.title) Pressed")

}
```

Which works to the point where the actual mosueDown events are caught and sent to the func (as expected)..

how do I get them working in the Radio Button mode? i.e. have their NSOnState and NSOffState toggle when the various buttons are clicked?

When I try and change the button type to Radio Button, it automatically flips back to "Switch"....

Cheers,

A

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html

Comment: That uses NSMatrix which has been depreciated. Hence my title "NSMAtrix alternative"... Please read the question again...

Comment: I do not believe NSMatrix has been deprecated.

Comment: @AdrianSluyters Please read the docs again.

Comment: So when I read this in the NSMatrix header, I'm reading incorrectly: `"/*
    NSMatrix is deprecated and will be unsupported in future releases.  For radio button grouping, sibling radio buttons that share the same action will operate in an exclusive mode.
 */"`

Comment: And in the 10.10 release notes `https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/` read the NSMatrix part

Comment: That is certainly interesting.

Comment: Would something like this work https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController

Comment: Indeed it would, but I was looking for a more "Generic" approach.. i.e. something which doesn't require the use of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Just wire all the radio buttons to the same target / action -- that is all you need to do https://youtu.be/yaJPJdZZ6CM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you specifically don't want to use `NSMatrix`...
First issue is that if you are using *square button style*, you can't use *radio type*. You want to use the *On Off type* in Interface Builder.

Here is the code I used for 4 buttons to test this out:

```swift
var buttonList : [NSButton] {
    return [button1, button2, button3, button4]
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: NSButton) {
    buttonList.forEach {
        $0.state = $0 == sender ? .on : .off
    }
}
```

As you can see, it iterates over all of the buttons, testing if it is the button that was pressed. It turns that button on while turning the other buttons off.
You will need to manage any state you want from there, or by checking the state of all of the buttons:

```
func whichButton() -> ActivityState {
   if button1.state == .on { return .one }
   if button2.state == .on { return .two }
   ...
}
```

where `ActivityState.one` is some enum case that you can use to determine which state you are in.

Comment: Thankyou! I guess the general comment Apple left behind in the NSMatrix header at RadioMode was a little too vague. But this is what I needed.

Comment: None of this management is necessary -- if all the radio buttons have the same target/action then you get the functionally for free. https://youtu.be/yaJPJdZZ6CM

Answer (score 11):

just give the NSRadioButtons the same superview and action. And as noted by Good Doug in his answer,

> […] if you are using square button style, you can't use radio type. You want to use the On Off type in Interface Builder.

I really don't think you want to have your action method set the state of all buttons in the group… let AppKit do that for you.

From [OS X Developer Release Notes: Cocoa Application Framework (10.10 and Earlier)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/)

> An NSButton configured as a radio button (with the -buttonType set to NSRadioButton), will now operate in a radio button group for applications linked on 10.8 and later. To have the button work in a radio group, use the same -action for each NSButton instance, and have the same superview for each button. When these conditions are met, checking one button (by changing the -state to 1), will uncheck all other buttons (by setting their -state to 0).

Comment: Yes -- this should be the checked answer. Just link them all the the same action and voila it works!  https://youtu.be/yaJPJdZZ6CM

Comment: This works well for the common case, but if you're like me and doing really fancy things with custom buttons across view hierarchies, @GoodDoug's answer works better

Comment: May I add a clarification, as "the same superview" condition is slightly incomplete here as well as in Apple's documentation. It's not enough to have the same superview for all buttons - you have to explicitly embed them into a superview in Interface Builder (for example, Custom View or Box). If you just drag two buttons into the same view and assign them the same action it won't work.

Answer (score -5):

I believe that you are looking for NSMatrix:[image]

You can configure this with as many rows and columns as  you like: [image]

You can then choose whether to allow a single choice or a variety:[image]

You capture the selection in your IBAction with any combination of `sender.selectedColumn` and `sender.selectedRow`

Comment: This answer is NOT a `NSMatrix` alternative.