# Mutually exclusive radio buttons for MacOS in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've got five radio buttons, and selecting one should deselect the others.

I've been over a lot of the questions here about radio buttons in Swift, but they're either for iOS or outdated versions of Swift, because Xcode isn't offering me options like ".isSelected". I've got ".isEnabled" but clearly semantics matter here, because "enabled" isn't the same thing as "selected" and it shows.

Writing my code as a series of "if-else" statements along these lines:

```
func disableUnselectedButtons() {
    if Button2.isEnabled == true {
        Button1.isEnabled = false
        Button3.isEnabled = false
        Button4.isEnabled = false
        Button5.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

results in a situation where I can select all five buttons, and can't DEselect any of them after another has been selected. I've tried variations of .on/.off as well, and can't find the right one for this situation.

It's also clumsy as heck to write a method with five if-else statements along those lines. So there's that.

What's the best way to go about implementing this?

Comment: See [NSButton RadioGroup (NSMatrix Alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832546/4244136)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your radio buttons have the same superview and have the same action then they should work as expected.

To set the same action for each of your radio buttons you can do one of the following.

If you are using Storyboards, open both storyboard and related NSViewController swift file. Ctrl-drag your first radio button to the swift file. Then do the same for each of the other radio buttons ensuring you are dragging onto the function generated from the first Ctrl-drag.

If you are creating the radio buttons in code then set the action parameter in the `init` for each radio button to be the same.

Comment: That's cool. I've never put multiple objects in the same action, so I need to figure that out, but they're in a stack view so I've got the superview part covered. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to approach this is to represent the buttons as a Set and then it's easy to iterate through them and configure their state.  The below code  actually allows for allowing multiple selections to support a scenario that wants to "select three of the six options".

```
let allButtons = Set(1...5). //or however many you want

func selectActiveButtons(_ activeButtons: Set<Int>, from allButtons: Set<Int>){
   let inactive = allButtons.subtracting(activeButtons)
   setButtonState(forButtons: inactive, isSelected: false)
   setButtonState(forButtons: activeButtons, isSelected: true)
}

func setButtonState(forButtons buttons: Set<Int>, isSelected: Bool) {
   buttons.forEach{
      //remove below line and replace with code to update buttons in UI
      print("Button \($0):  \(isSelected ? "Selected" : "Unselected")")
   }
}

// select buttons 1 & 3.  
//If wanting a "classic" radio button group just use one value in the arrayLiteral.
selectActiveButtons(Set(arrayLiteral: 1,3), from: allButtons)
```

Comment: I forgot UIComponents are hashable - just add buttons to the set rather than index them.

Comment: How could one add buttons to the set rather index them?

let allButtons = Set<Int>(arrayLiteral: radioButton1.hashValue,    radioButton2.hashValue, radioButton3.hashValue) 

The line above does not work, so how should it be written?

Comment: @TurboPascal add the button, not its hashvalue.   `let buttons = Set(arrayLiteral: button1, button2)`